# noise when i use cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, opencv

i wanted to extract the letters from this image:
[image]

when i tried to use connectedComponentsWithStats  i got alot of labels but they were noisy like this example:
[image]
this is the part of my code that supposed to extract the letters:

```
def ExtractLetters(img):
    blur_radius = 0.1
    nlabel, labels,stats,centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img)
    thresh_size=30
    for i in range(1, nlabel):
        img = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
        if (stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH] > thresh_size) or (stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]>thresh_size):
            img[labels == i] = 255
            img = 255 - img
            cv2.imshow("test", img)
            cv2.waitKey()
```

Do you know why these noises appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before find  connectedComponentsWithStats, need convert image RGBA to grayscale and thresholding.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your binary image was saved as JPEG, introducing compression artifacts. When reading the image back in, it no longer has only two different values.

Thresholding the image before doing connected component analysis would solve your problem.